# Grabbing field from a query set in Django

Tags: django

I'm not quite sure if I asked this question correctly in the title, but I am trying to achieve the following.

I have a series of lists that are entered by a user and I am trying to print the individual list to individual HTML pages.

Everything works fine, except instead of just the list name printing, it returns it in some set form.

```
[<newlist: hi>] (when it should just return hi)
```

I am assuming the reason is, my views contains the following line

```
listname = request.user.newlist_set.filter(list_name__iexact=listname)
```

so when I print {{ listname }} it returns it like the set listed above. How can I get around this and just grab the name in the newlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` operation always returns `list` so you can display it using loop:

```
{% for l in listname %}
    {{ l }}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can just call method `first` if you are sure that it always exists and only one:

```
listname = request.user.newlist_set.filter(list_name__iexact=listname).first()
```

If there is no listname then it's `None`. You can check this in template:

```
{% if listname %}
     {{ listname }}
{% else %}
     No list with this name.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In many situations you'll want to use `get` instead of `first` if you're expecting exactly one match - eg fetching something by PK. `get` will raise an exception if nothing matches.